# scipy.ndimage.interpolate.affine_transform fails

Tags: python, scipy, affinetransform

This code:

```
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import affine_transform
import numpy as np
...
nzoom = 1.2
newimage = affine_transform(self.image, matrix=np.array([[nzoom, 0],[0, nzoom]]))
```

fails with:

```
RuntimeError: affine matrix has wrong number of rows
```

What's the problem with the matrix? I also tried `matrix=[nzoom, nzoom]`, which according to my reading of documentation should do the same, and it fails the same way.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why the original code does not work with a 2x2 matrix is because the image in question is 3-dimensional. Mind you, the 3rd dimension is`[R,G,B]`, but `scipy.ndimage` does not know about non-spatial dimensions; it treats all dimensions as spatial. The examples using 2x2 matrices were all 2D "gray" images.

**Solution #1:**

`affine_transform` maps output coordinates `o` to source (input) coordinates `s` as:

```
s = numpy.dot(matrix,o) + offset
```

where `matrix` and `offset` are arguments to `affine_transform`. In the case of a multichannel image we don't want to transform the 3rd dimension. I.e., we want the source coordinates corresponding to an output point

```
o == [x, y, z]  # column vector
```

to be

```
s == [c00*x + c01*y + dx, c10*x + c11*y + dy, z]  # column vector
```

To achieve that result we need

```
matrix = [[ c00, c01,  0],
          [ c10, c11,  0],
          [   0,   0,  1]]

offset = [dx, dy, 0]  # column vector
```

**Solution #2:**

An alternative solution is to split the RGB image in 3 channels, transform each channel separately, and combine them together,

```
r = rgb[..., 0]
g = rgb[..., 1]
b = rgb[..., 2]
matrix = np.array([[c00, c01], [c10, c11]])
offset = [dx dy]
r = affine_transform(r, matrix=matrix, offset=offset)
g = affine_transform(g, matrix=matrix, offset=offset)
b = affine_transform(b, matrix=matrix, offset=offset)
rgb = np.dstack((r, g, b))
```

I have not timed either solution, but I expect #2 to be slower that #1.